# Lining up elements on CSS dropdown

Tags: css

How would I line up my dropdown elements with the **clicker**?

Here is my CSS code

```
#header_dropdown {
    float: right;
}
.click-nav {
    width: 200px;
}
.click-nav ul {
    position: relative;
}
.click-nav ul li {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.click-nav ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
}
.click-nav ul .clicker {
    position: relative;
    background: #2284B5;
    color: #FFF;
}
.click-nav ul .clicker:hover, .click-nav ul .active {
    background: #196F9A;
}
.click-nav ul li a {
    transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
    display: block;
    background: #FFF;
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.click-nav ul li a:hover {
    background: #F2F2F2;
}
/* Fallbacks */
 .click-nav .no-js ul {
    display: none;
}
.click-nav .no-js:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/KVrFM/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the padding from the sub-menu `ul`.

http://jsfiddle.net/KVrFM/1/

I modified your anonymous function to add the active class to the `li` rather than the anchor tag using jQuery `parent()`.

```js
$('.clicker').parent().toggleClass('active');
```

Then I added the following CSS rule.  When doing drop-down and fly-out menus in CSS it is helpful to use the child combinator `>`.  Having a rule like `.click-nav ul` will target **all** `ul` that are descendants of `.click-nav`.  Changing that rule to `.click-nav > ul` will only target `ul`s that are **children** of `.click-nav` and **not** grandchildren etc.

```css
.active ul {
     padding: 0;
}
```